# Access violation while initializing matlab-compiler dll / lib in c++ only during debugging

Tags: c++, matlab, dllimport, matlab-compiler, lib

what I'm trying to do is integrate a MATLAB-Compiler dll/lib to an new c++ project.

I followed this instruction: [How do I integrate my C++ shared Library generated from MATLAB](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/182851-how-do-i-integrate-my-c-shared-library-generated-from-matlab-r2013b-in-visual-studio-2013#answer_171111) which seams working good (no build errors and intelisense is working good, so it seams all required information are there).

I'm using a very simple mathlab code / function for testing:

```
function output = extest( arg1,arg2 )
    output = arg1+arg2;
end
```

And the "default" c++ code for matlab functions:

```
#include "extest.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    mclmcrInitialize();
    if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0)){

        std::cerr << "could not initialize the application properly" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
        if(!extestInitialize()){
            std::cerr << "could not initialize the library properly" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            try{

                //code itself (not jet reached therefore removed)

            }catch(const mwException& e){
              std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
              return -2;
            }
            catch(...){
              std::cerr << "Unexpected error thrown" << std::endl;
              return -3;  
            }
            extestTerminate();
        }
        mclTerminateApplication();
        return 0;
}
```

After e few moments after the debugger tries to run the line `if(!extestInitialize())` the following error gets thrown.

> Exception thrown at 0x000002BF72E0EE55 in DllTestingCpp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

[image]

I can hit visual studios `continue >` button and it is continued after lets say 20x click on it. Starting the code by `ctrl + F5` (without debugging) everything is working good.

Any ideas why this happens in debug mode? Or better how I can get rid of this error?

PS: `extest` is my lib name and using Matlab R2017a 64bit and Visual Studio 2017 (debugging with x64),

Comment: I was getting a similar error after deploying a `.net` assembly. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680338/exception-when-initialize-dll-in-c-sharp-generated-by-matlab-compiler/44680616#44680616). Try disabling the jit on matlab. Here are a couple of links. [link1](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79738-calling-new-on-matlab-generated-class-from-dot-net-crushes-the-app-m_interpreter-dll), [link2](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/293615-mcr_r2013a_win64-net-framework-4-5-2). I am not sure how relevant this is to c++ though..

Comment: hi, yes it does look very similar, but I'm not sure how to use the solution within c++

Comment: Turning off the jit when starting matlab compiler could be a start, this does not depend if you compile for C# of C++.

Comment: nope no change. error still persists even if I turn off the "JIT" via `feature accel off` as explained here https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237478

Comment: well I found out, that this issue only appears in `debugging` mode within visual studio. not without debugging. Without debugging everything works great ... still strange but working for now :D

Comment: That's really strange.. I would suggest to edit your question and include this info

Comment: I did modified it.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem (Matlab2017 + VS 2015) for me.
Probably there is some conflict with java used by MATLAB.

I've fixed it by

```
const char *args[] = {"-nojvm"};
const int count = sizeof(args) / sizeof(args[0]);
mclInitializeApplication(args, count))
```

instead of

```
mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0)
```

Comment: You will lose UI of Matlab (do you really need them when call it from C++?), but anyway it's better then access violation

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue(using VS2019) and I found the following answer here:
https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/182851-how-do-i-integrate-my-c-shared-library-generated-from-matlab-r2013b-in-visual-studio-2013

> I encountered this same issue and reported it to Mathworks. They responded that for VS2013 and later, the debugger is set to break when 0xc0000005 occurs, even though in this case it is handled by the JVM.
>   The fix is to go to Debug>Windows>Exception Settings>Win32 and uncheck '0xc0000005 Access Violation'. In VS2012, this setting is unchecked by default.

This seems to work o.k.