# .NET Assembly issue with MATLAB

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, visual-studio

I followed this guide : http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-cc-application-with-matlab-code-1.html and try to build a.NET Application as mentioned in the guide.

I am stuck with the System.TypeInitializationException Error which I could not resolve. Can somebody teach me how should I debug this issue? I am a complete beginner. I will also attach the screenshot here.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLnb4.png)

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680338/exception-when-initialize-dll-in-c-sharp-generated-by-matlab-compiler/44680616#44680616)

Comment: The issue is resolved by adding the path of the MATLAB runtime folder into the Path of Environment Variables, e.g.path (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v92\runtime\win64)

Comment: I'll edit this into the answer for future reference